# Is it possible to change text colour when different text is set?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I know the title doesn't describe too good but I was wondering if there was a certain code to type into Visual Basic to make the text in a textbox change colour when the text changes.

Here is my code:

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
            txtnetwork.Text = "Connected"
        Else
            txtnetwork.Text = "Disconnected"
        End If
```

So is there a way of making the "Connected" text Green, and the "Disconnected" text Red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just set the [`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        txtnetwork.ForeColor = Color.Green
        txtnetwork.Text = "Connected"
    Else
        txtnetwork.ForeColor = Color.Red
        txtnetwork.Text = "Disconnected"
    End If
```